# In Excel can I write a formula that will calculate the sum of a column based on the contents of another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel can I write a formula that will calculate the sum of a column based on the contents of another column? In the example below, the formula would output '12' if I wanted to see all sales with a category of 'Email'.

This was my idea, but it doesn't work.

`=SUMIF(table1[Sales],AND(table1[Category]="Email",table1[Subcategory]="Content"))`

```
A       | B         | C
-----------------------------------
Sales   | Category  | Subcategory
===================================
10      | Email     | Content
-----------------------------------
5       | Web       | Non-Content
-----------------------------------
2       | Email     | Content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want SUMIFS() with an `S`:

```
=SUMIFS(table1[Sales],table1[Category],"Email",table1[Subcategory],"Content")
```

Criteria are always done in twos:

- A range the same size as the one being summed
- The criteria as a string(`=` being the default)

You can add others or only have one:

```
=SUMIFS(table1[Sales],table1[Category],"Email")
```

Which does the same as SUMIF() with slightly different order of criteria.